# How to show different dropdowns and get their values on selection of value from a dropdown

Tags: javascript

I am using dropdown which have 2 values. On the selection of values from this dropdown i am showing 1 of 2 dropdowns on selection condition. I am using jquery to show and hide these dropdowns. The problem is that i am not getting the all the values from the dropdown. Let me explain by exapmle: There are 2 options in dropdown: Contract and Exception. It works fine with Contract but when i select Exception it shows the correct values in dropdown(er_hidden_div) but when i select them it and use alert it shows the old values form Contract(cc_hidden_div) which i have selected before: Below is my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#PrgDrpDwn_Program').change(function(){
    var value = $("#PrgDrpDwn_Program option:selected").val();
       if(value=='Contract Compliance')
       {
            alert(value);
            $('#cc_hidden_div').css('display','block');
            $('#er_hidden_div').css('display','none');  
       }
       else
        {
            alert(value);
            $('#er_hidden_div').css('display','block');
            $('#cc_hidden_div').css('display','none');
       }
    });
 });

        $('select[name="PrgDrpDwn1_Area"]').change(function(){
        var value_area= $("select[name='PrgDrpDwn1_Area'] option:selected").val();
        alert(value_area);
        });
  });
</script>
```

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="miscellaneous_program" name="miscellaneous_program" class="" style="display:none;">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Select Program New:</label>
                <select id="PrgDrpDwn_Program" name="PrgDrpDwn_Program" class="PrgDrpDwn_Program custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--emerald w348">
                    <option value="0">----Select----</option>
                    <option value="Contract Compliance">Contract Compliance</option>
                    <option value="Exception Reporting">Exception Reporting</option>
                </select>               
     </div>

<div class="form-group" id="cc_hidden_div" name="cc_hidden_div" class="cc_hidden_div" style="display:none;">
      <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Area New</label>
            <select id="PrgDrpDwn_cc" name="PrgDrpDwn1_Area" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--emerald w348">
                    <option value="-1">----Select----</option>
                    <option value="Staples">Staples</option>
                    <option value="GdfSuez">GdfSuez</option>
                    <option value="Fedex">Fedex</option>
            </select>
    </div>

<div class="form-group" id="er_hidden_div" name="er_hidden_div" class="er_hidden_div" style="display:none;">
      <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Area New</label>
            <select id="PrgDrpDwn_er" name="PrgDrpDwn1_Area" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--emerald w348">
                    <option value="-1">----Select----</option>
                    <option value="Staples">Staples</option>
                    <option value="PCard Due">PCard Due</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these with the above code to get the values by request and compare the values as follows:

```
   $dropdown_program=$_REQUEST["PrgDrpDwn_Program"];
   $dropdown_area_cc=$_REQUEST["PrgDrpDwn1_Area_cc"];
   $dropdown_area_er=$_REQUEST["PrgDrpDwn1_Area_er"];
   $dropdown_area_rr=$_REQUEST["PrgDrpDwn1_Area_rr"];
----------------------------------------------------------
elseif($_REQUEST["select_import"] == "Miscellaneous")
if($dropdown_area_cc=="Staples")
{}
else{}
if($dropdown_area_cc=="Gdfsuez")
{}
else{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code . Use #-id selectors

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        {  
            $('#PrgDrpDwn_Program').change(function()
            {
                var value = $("#PrgDrpDwn_Program option:selected").val();
                if(value=='Contract Compliance')
                {
                    alert(value);
                    $('#cc_hidden_div').css('display','block');
                    $('#er_hidden_div').css('display','none');  
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(value);
                    $('#er_hidden_div').css('display','block');
                    $('#cc_hidden_div').css('display','none');
                }
            });


            $('#PrgDrpDwn_cc').change(function()
            {
                var value_area= $("#PrgDrpDwn_cc option:selected").val();
                alert(value_area);
            });

            $('#PrgDrpDwn_er').change(function()
            {
                var value_area= $("#PrgDrpDwn_er option:selected").val();
                alert(value_area);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts but i looks like it does not solve my problem. I am expecting a solution in which i get any value from these in one variable when i request it in the form to save to DB. Actually i am checking multiple conditions there before like if(PrgDrpDwn_Program=='Compliance'){if(PrgDrpDwn_=='Staples'){do this} if(PrgDrpDwn_=='GdfSuez'){do this}}.. Cheching these conditions for different variables will be very complex.. Plz can you help me on this part..

Comment: Thanks man, finally it worked for me with some changes. Thanks a lot.